# Detect if VisibleChanged is true or false

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a handler for a C# panels VisibleChanged event. But how do I detect if the visibility is being set to true or false??

```
public void Parent_VisibleChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
       if(Visible = true)
       {
         // do what i want to do
       }

    }
```

Comment: Try to check equality with `==`, not with `=`

Comment: No need to compare a bool at all. Besides, it's the wrong `Visible` property.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `==` and not `=`

```
if(Visible == true)
```

Comment: Apologies I meant that the handler is for the current controls Parent container.  I did if(this.Parent.Visible == true) and it worked.

Comment: This `== true` is superfluous.

Answer (score 2):

You should do something like this inside the event:

```
if (((Panel)sender).Visible)
    MessageBox.Show("Visible.");
else
    MessageBox.Show("Not Visible.");
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are two ways:

```
private void panel1_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // use sending object
    Panel panel = sender as Panel;

    if (panel.Visible == false)
        ;

    // alternate use name of object
    if (panel1.Visible == false)
        ;
}
```

Comment: Comparing a bool is rather useless. You wouldn't write `if ((i==8)==false)`, would you?

Comment: "Comparing a bool is rather useless."  I find that statement to be nonsensical.   As to personal style, I find it easier to read the way I did it.  If you want to have long tedious discussions about style, this is not the proper venue.

Comment: What could be easier or clearer than `if (!panel.Visible)`, i.e. "if not Visible"? But, sorry, didn't know that's your style. I only know it as a beginner's mistake. Don't want to discuss style...